# Is it considered 'bikur cholim' to call someone who's sick?

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, choleh-sick, phone

When someone calls a friend who is sick to see how he's doing and to wish him a refuah shleima, is that technically a fulfillment of mitzvahs bikur cholim?

Comment: Partially, see Minchas Yitzchak 2:84 ,an actual visit is considered bikur cholim, on phone seems more like a tovas hacholeh which is also something, but not complete bikur cholim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Nishmat Avraham](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578197125.html) vol. 2 p. 262 answers your question

[image]

Comment: Is a visit by Skype one cut above a phone call, or no different?