# Is virtual presence considered Bikur cholim for the sick

Tags: halacha, technology, choleh-sick, yoreh-deah, chesed-kindness

Is looking  at a sick person through zoom or another video camera service considered “visiting” then for the purposes of the mitzvah of Bikur cholim? Or no, does it have to be physical presence to count?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/109835/13811

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rav Daniel Neustadt [writes](https://torah.org/torah-portion/weekly-halacha-5772-vayechi/):

> Contemporary poskim discuss the issue of fulfilling bikur cholim by
> means of the telephone. The consensus is that while certain
> aspects of the mitzvah can be performed over the telephone, other
> aspects cannot. They rule, therefore, that when a personal visit is
> impossible, a phone call should be made so that the mitzvah is at
> least partially fulfilled. (Igros Moshe, Y.D. 1:223; Kisvei Rav Henkin 2:88; Minchas Yitzchak 2:84; Chelkas Yaakov 2:128; Tzitz Eliezer, Ramas Rachel 8:6; Yechaveh Da’as 3:83.)

Seemingly, a video-call would be at least just as good as a phone call for bikur cholim, which is a decent alternative if attending in person is not an available option. (The [OU suggests](https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/can-one-fulfill-the-mitzvah-of-bikur-cholim-by-phone-or-by-zoom/?category) this reasoning as well for Zoom calls.)